# Pressure in Skoog Instrumental Analysis Problem 27-22b (gas chromatography)

Tags: analytical-chemistry, chromatography, erratum

Problem 27-22b in:

Skoog; Holler; Crouch. Principles of Instrumental Analysis. Thomson Brooks/Cole (publisher varies by country)

asks for corrected retention volumes.

A compressibility factor, $j$ is needed to compute them.

Answers that I find online all get $j = 0.915$, and a dead volume $V_M$ of $\pu{8.3 mL}$, which agrees with the solution in the back of the book.
However they seem to use a unit conversion factor of $\pu{5.17 torr psi-1}$, which is off by a factor of $10$.

In my analysis $\frac{P_i}P$ should be ($\frac{\pu{2.727 bar}  }{\pu{0.997 bar}}$), $j$ should be $0.500$, and $V_M$ should be $\pu{4.5 mL}$.

Am I wrong?

> **27-22**
>
> A GC column was operated under the following conditions: 
> Column:
>   1.10 m ✕ 2.0 mm, packed with Chromosorb P: weight of stationary liquid added, 1.40 g; density of liquid, 1.02 g/mL 
> pressures: inlet, 26.1
>   psi above room; room, 748 torr 
> measured outlet flow rate: 25.3
>   mL/min 
> temperature: room, 21.2°C; column, 102.0°C 
> retention
>   times: air, 18.0 s; methyl acetate, 1.98 min; methyl propionate, 4.16
>   min; methyl n-butyrate, 7.93 min 
> peak widths of esters at base:
>   0.19, 0.39, and 0.79, respectively
>
> Calculate 
> (a) the average flow rate in the column. 
> (b) the
>   corrected retention volumes for air and the three esters. 
> (c) the
>   specific retention volumes for the three components. 
> (d) the
>   distribution constants for each of the esters. 
> (e) a corrected
>   retention volume and retention time for methyl n-hexanoate.

Comment: I'm not at all familiar with chromotography, could you add some calculations so that those of us not famliar are more able to chime in?

Comment: Page 197,
https://www.slideshare.net/LEANNEDESOUSA/principios-de-anlise-instrumental-6ed-skoog-resolues